# How can I write a shortcut to a program with spaces in the path and use cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-7

I tried this in my shortcut target input field but it doesn't work. The dialog box gives me an error message invalid path? `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start /high /affinity 3 D:\The
 Elder Scrolls V - Skyrim\skse_loader.exe"`. Notice the spaces in the pathname. Is this the space character that need to be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The start option need a title to work: http://www.vistax64.com/gaming/197915-setting-processor-affinity-made-easy.html. `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C START "Skyrim" /high /affinity 3 "D:\The Elder Scrolls V - Skyrim\skse_loader.exe"`

Comment: Looks like you surrounding the path in quotes also may have helped.  That's the part that helped solve my similar problem, as I just Answered separately (focusing on the quotes).

Answer (score 3):

From your path

> "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start /high /affinity 3 D:\The/ Elder Scrolls V - Skyrim\skse_loader.exe"

The following part, and especially the slash seems to be most suspicious, since it is not allowed in path:

> D:\The/ Elder

I would re-write your target using the short 8.3 name (it is the fake name in the example just to show what it should like):

> "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C start /high /affinity 3 D:\TheElde~1\skse_l~1.exe

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too fast. I've tried to escaped the space character with the slash character but I forget to delete in my question. About your suggesting it doesn't work. The path opens a terminal with the path but it is not starting the program.

Comment: Try converting your long path into short one and you won't need the quotes. You can use `dir /x` to see the short paths: you'll need that for your Elder Scroll folder and for executable only.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar in Windows 10 where I needed to append an argument to my Eclipse program shortcut's target, where the argument was a path with a space (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\javaw) [note the space in 'Program Files']...

**If you just need to resolve the space in the path, surround the path in quotes.**

So my argument became:  *"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\javaw"*

Accepted Answer by @Phpdevpad helped me figure this out, but the quotes weren't focused on in that solution, so I made this separate Answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked.
The only thing that worked for me was the following abomination:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start /high /affinity 3 D:\\The\ Elder\ Scrolls\ V\ -\ Skyrim\\skse_loader.exe
```